# repeating table problem

Tags: development

I created content type and add them on custom list in visual studio.
 I want to use some of my list item columns like repating table columns.

Is there any solution or alternative way except infopath solution to the repating table? or similar thing on visual studio?

Comment: Can you explain more on what you mean by "use some of my list item columns like repeating table columns"? You can use [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466219(v=office.12).aspx) in Visual Studio as a customizable/codeable ListView!

Comment: I mean that, i created a content type and its surely a grid.But want to show some of them in my list as a repating table for ex: column1 column2 and column3 in a repating table but column4 not.